# Define Function with Expected Typeclass and Sub-class Type Parameter

Tags: scala

Given:

```
scala> sealed trait Father
defined trait Father

scala> case object Son extends Father
defined object Son
```

and a type-class:

```
scala> trait Foo[A] 
defined trait Foo
```

Next, I defined the function, `f`, which, as I understand it, expects the type parameter, `A`, to be a sub-class of `Father` and have a typeclass instance of `Foo`.

```
scala> def f[A <: Father : Foo](x: Father): String = x.toString
f: [A <: Father](x: Father)(implicit evidence$1: Foo[A])String
```

Then, I defined an instance:

```
scala> implicit val fooFather = new Foo[Father] {}
fooFather: Foo[Father] = $anon$1@4f25b795
```

And lastly I called it:

```
scala> f(Son)
res0: String = Son
```

However, it seems to me that `f` could've been written as:

```
def f[A <: Father](x: Father)(implicit ev: Foo[A]): String = x.toString
```

Is there a preferred way of writing the above function `f`? And, is there a difference between them?

Comment: The REPL output from the first `f` clearly shows they are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they are the exact same thing.

*Context bounds*, which btw is how `Foo` in `def f[A <: Father : Foo]` is called, has one problem. If in the body of the method you need to refer to the implicit parameter you end up needing to use `implicitly[Foo[A]]` which in inconvenient, ie

```
def f[A <: Father : Foo](x: Father): String = {
  implicitly[Foo[A]].ifFooHadAMethod // couldn't think of a better example :)
  x.toString
}
```

That's why in a lot of code out there people use

```
def f[A <: Father : Foo](x: Father)(implicit ev:Foo[A]): String = {
  ev.ifFooHadAMethod // couldn't think of a better example :)
  x.toString
}
```

Personally I prefer the 2nd case only if I need to refer to the implicit parameter, otherwise I prefer to use context bounds.

Comment: Thanks. Why do you say that using `implicitly[...]` is inconvenient - since it's more to type than `ev. ifFooHadAMethod`?

Comment: Well, arguably inconvenient. You also need to provide the type, in this case, it's easy, but what if you need a projection like `{ type X[A] = Bar[A,B] }#X`, for example? It's not only annoying, it's error prone, some times the trade off of using context bounds just don't pays off.